# Why does this AWS AppSync list operation using OR return an empty list even when part of the OR returns truthy values?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify, boolean-logic, aws-appsync

Context:

I am trying to query for all notifications sent or received by a user in my mobile app, and am getting results that (I think) show that AWS AppSync's OR filtering is slightly broken (or that I do not understand how it works)

Note that I am performing these queries using AWS AppSync Queries, but the results are consistent when using their GUI or by sending the queries from the React Native app

Here is my list query using the OR statement

```
query listAllNotifsForUser {
  listNotifications(filter: {sentUserID: {eq: "arbitrary-id-1"}, or: {receivedUserID: {eq: "arbitrary-id-1"}}}) {
    items {
      id
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

This query returns

```
  "data": {
"listNotifications": {
  "items": [],
  "nextToken": null
}
```

Here is my query when listing specifically notifications that have the sentUserID equal to arbitrary-id-1 (no OR statement, only the first half of the OR filter from above)

```
query listAllNotifsForUser {
  listNotifications(filter: {sentUserID: {eq: "arbitrary-id-1"}}) {
    items {
      id
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

and here is the result from that query

```
{
  "data": {
    "listNotifications": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "88d204c8-7346-4f69-bc6a-c1e5db1ce5f4"
        },
        {
          "id": "29e03351-75f0-46b2-933b-c3cca43a6067"
        },
        {
          "id": "e21cf81a-7cb3-4331-90af-6ef266f75820"
        },
        {
          "id": "17b42150-ae7c-4852-a58c-85d73ed2e247"
        }
      ],
      "nextToken": null
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the ONLY difference between these two queries is the removal of the 'or' and the second half of the boolean check, which from basic knowledge of programming, one would not imagine this should ever limit the results compared to a single boolean statement

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my AppSync console and it worked:

```
query MyQuery {
  listJobListings(filter: {or: [{ city: {eq: "Chongqing City"} }, { city: {eq: "Beijing"} }]}) {
    nextToken
    items {
      city
    }
  }
}
```

Which means you'll need to do this:

```
query listAllNotifsForUser {
  listNotifications(filter: {or: [{ sentUserID: {eq: "user-id"} }, { sentUserID: {eq: "user-id"} }]}) {
    items {
      id
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

More information [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/query-data/q/platform/js/#compound-filters)